# Python requests response getting wrong url

Tags: python, python-requests, httprequest

I'm trying to request data from a url, but constantly get `404 error`

```
session = requests.Session()
GET = session.get("http://www.inmet.gov.br/sonabra/pg_dspDadosCodigo_sim.php?QTgwNA==", timeout=1)
GET.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(GET.text, 'html.parser')
imgNumber  = soup.img.get("src").split("imgNum=", maxsplit=1)[1]
decodeNumber = str(base64.b64decode(imgNumber), 'utf-8')

request = {"dtaini": self.start, "aleaValue": imgNumber,
                  "aleaNum": decodeNumber, "dtafim": self.end}

POST = session.post(stationURL, data=request)
POST.raise_for_status()
```

logging result:

```
urllib3.connectionpool: DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.inmet.gov.br
urllib3.connectionpool: DEBUG: http://www.inmet.gov.br:80 "GET /sonabra/pg_dspDadosCodigo_sim.php?QTgwNA==  HTTP/1.1" 200 690
urllib3.connectionpool: DEBUG: /sonabra/pg_dspDadosCodigo_sim.php?QTgwNA==  HTTP/1.1" 302 498
urllib3.connectionpool: DEBUG: http://www.inmet.gov.br:80 "GET /sonabra/log2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 302
```

I'm not sure what happened as it used to work some months ago and the request do work at browser. I appreciate any help or advise.

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing to do with python i even got 404 just by using a web browser try a different URL or contact the server owner if you think this should not happen.

Comment: Sorry, have corrected the url, I've posted it after hours of tries very and my consciousness was in more near to bed than my body... But I still gave the same problem.

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti ok, como voce resolveu o problema? estou com um script antigo com o mesmo pane.

Comment: @relima eu simplesmente depurei novamente o request em um navegador para verificar se o Form havia mudado, e este foi o caso... Como eu expliquei na minha própria resposta faltou atenção/café hehehe.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I was getting confusing debugging showing me old forms in both Chrome and Firefox, the reason for it to not work is because the form data interface changed from:

```
request = {"dtaini": self.start, "aleaValue": imgNumber,
           "aleaNum": decodeNumber, "dtafim": self.end}
```

to:

```
request = {"aleaValue": aleaValue, "xaleaValue": xaleaValue,
           "aleaNum": aleaNum, "xID": xID,
           "dtaini": self.start, "dtafim": self.end}
```

My suggestion to someone with similar problem is to take a rest, look things better next morning, with coffee...